# pass other column inside spread with duplicate identifiers

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, spread

I have the below dataframe where I am trying to `spread` the `feature_code` by passing the `actv_amt` so that I get the corresponding `actv_amt` for the corresponding `feature` code. I am trying to pass as `count_FEATURE = ACTV_AMT` it is passing the value but not merging the data.

for reference, I asked a question earlier
[take unique count and sum each unique values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118516/take-unique-count-and-sum-each-unique-values-in-r)

```
Input type: 1
ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO   ACTV_CODE   ACTV_AMT    AB_NO   FEATURE_CODE    L_NU    
7/27/16 7/27/16 265       O          15          1      INTEREST        855          
7/27/16 7/27/16 265       O          14          1      INTEREST        855 

getting Output
ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO   ACTV_CODE   ACTV_AMT    AB_NO   FEATURE_INTEREST     L_NU   
7/27/16 7/27/16 265      O           29          1             2             855

Expected output:
ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO   ACTV_CODE   ACTV_AMT    AB_NO   FEATURE_INTEREST     L_NU   
7/27/16 7/27/16 265      O           29          1             29             855
```

Input type 2:

```
Input
ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO   ACTV_CODE   ACTV_AMT    AB_NO   FEATURE_CODE    L_NU    
7/27/16 7/27/16 265            O          15       1     INTEREST        855          
7/27/16 7/27/16 265            O          14       1     INSTALLMENT   855    

Getting output:
ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO   ACTV_CODE   ACTV_AMT    AB_NO   INTEREST INSTALLMENT     L_NU   
7/Expected7/16 265          O           29           1      1          1           855 

Expected output:
ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO   ACTV_CODE   ACTV_AMT    AB_NO   INTEREST INSTALLMENT     L_NU   
7/27/16 7/27/16 265        O           29           1      15         14           855
```

Code implemented:

```
dt %>%
  group_by(AB_NO,LO_NO,L_NU)%>% 
  mutate(ACTV_AMT = sum(ACTV_AMT),
         ST_DATE = min(ST_DATE),
         ND_DATE = max(ND_DATE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(id = row_number(),
         FEATURE_CODE = paste0("FTR_", FEATURE_CODE),
         ACTV_CODE = paste0("ACTV_", ACTV_CODE),
         count_FEATURE = 1,
         count_ACTV = 1) %>%
  spread(FEATURE_CODE, count_FEATURE) %>%
  spread(ACTV_CODE, count_ACTV) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  group_by(ST_DATE, ND_DATE, LO_NO, ACTV_AMT, AB_NO, L_NU) %>%
  summarise_all(sum, na.rm=T) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Can anyone help me in getting the expected output.

Comment: @Hardikgupta what do you mean by dput

Comment: @Hardikgupta I shared my data above or refer the link you will get it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
library(reshape2)

df <- read.table(text = "ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO   ACTV_CODE   ACTV_AMT    AB_NO   FEATURE_CODE    L_NU    
7/27/16 7/27/16 265       O          15          1      INTEREST        855          
7/27/16 7/27/16 265       O          14          1      INTEREST        855", header = T)

dcast(df, ST_DATE+ND_DATE+LO_NO+ACTV_CODE+AB_NO+L_NU~FEATURE_CODE, value.var = "ACTV_AMT", fun.aggregate = sum)

output:
-------
  ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO ACTV_CODE AB_NO L_NU INTEREST
1 7/27/16 7/27/16   265         O     1  855       29

input2:
-------
df <- read.table(text = "ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO   ACTV_CODE   ACTV_AMT    AB_NO   FEATURE_CODE    L_NU    
7/27/16 7/27/16 265            O          15       1     INTEREST        855          
7/27/16 7/27/16 265            O          14       1     INSTALLMENT   855", header = T)

dcast(df, ST_DATE+ND_DATE+LO_NO+ACTV_CODE+AB_NO+L_NU~FEATURE_CODE, value.var = "ACTV_AMT", fun.aggregate = sum)

output:
-------
  ST_DATE ND_DATE LO_NO ACTV_CODE AB_NO L_NU INSTALLMENT INTEREST
1 7/27/16 7/27/16   265         O     1  855          14       15
```

Comment: but I need so consider max min of dates

Comment: I am considering the min and max values of the dates how do I consider from the above code

Comment: I didn't underdstand what you are saying